# Extrude Region (Vertex Normals) Extruding faces individually

Tags: normals, extrude

I have an issue with extruding along Vertex Normals. The faces extrude independently.

When I select the extrusion type with the proper faces selected:

### [image: Selecting Extrude Type]

The faces extrude individually and don't stay with each other:
[image: Results of Extrusion]
I have my pivot center set on Median Point which has been mentioned in some of the other posts. I am following a tutorial and can see it work correctly in the video. I also saw in another post that it could be because one of the faces isn't linked correctly. All of these faces were created with other extrusions and as far as I can tell everything is linked correctly.

I am running Blender Version 2.79b. I also loaded my file in version 2.78c with the same results.

I don't see a way to upload the blender file here so I tossed it out on Dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xrt263hwd2n6ibj/SpaceShip.blend?dl=0

Any help would be very much appreciated.

J.R.

Comment: You have duplicate geometry everywhere

Comment: I have been working off of a video series that teaches various techniques. It is focused more on showing how things work than making it efficient.

Comment: He is referring to the "failed extrusions". DO NOT just right click and assume the extrude ended. It actually duplicated everything and "extruded", but didn't move anything, and kept it all where it was. So now there are two vertices where there was one. Instead press esc.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it's not esc. That gives the same problem. I haven't used Blender much in so long. Just undo after you have one you don't like. That's easiest. And, yes, that is most likely what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have the pivot center set to "**individual origins**." This causes each face to extrude along its own normal axis.

[image]

However, this wouldn't *normally* cause the problem you are having. The only reason it is causing it in this case is because you have **duplicate geometry**. This is most likely because of failed attempts at extrusion. DO NOT just right click and assume the extrude ended. It actually duplicated everything and "extruded", but didn't move anything, and kept it all where it was. So now there are two vertices where there was one. Just undo after you have one you don't like. That's the easiest safe way to get rid of an extrude. You can see this in my example scene, extruding to identical meshes, except one I "canceled" one extrude between each face. This means there **is** duplicate geometry on the upper object.

[image]

By simply dragging the face out you can see what I mean by extra geometry. You could see by the little dot in the middle of the edge that there was another face taking up "zero space", right on top of itself. When I pull away the main face it *stretches* the extra face out so you can see it. This unselected extra face is what's causing your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you So Much. I am new to this and have been absolutely losing my mind. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. I will be more careful in the future with the extrude function.